# Simple HTML update of a variable based on the value of another

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have some code on my website that updates an element based on the value of a price slider.

```
$("#te_li_yr_seats_html").html(te_li_yr_price.innerHTML/215)
```

The above code is working fine, and **#te_li_yr_seats_html** will always be a number between 2 and 8.

I want to update a second element based on this calculated value.

I've added my full code below and then a pseudo code snippet of what I'm trying to do. I hope that's clear.

Thank you in advance for any help.

```
var te_li_yr_price = document.getElementById("te_li_yr_price_base");
var te_li_yr_slider = document.getElementById("te_li_yr_slider");

te_li_yr_price.innerHTML = te_li_yr_slider.value;

te_li_yr_slider.oninput = function() {
te_li_yr_price.innerHTML = this.value;

$("#te_li_yr_price_html").html(te_li_yr_price.innerHTML.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","))
$('input[id="te_li_yr_price_form"]').val(te_li_yr_price.innerHTML)

$("#te_li_yr_seats_html").html(te_li_yr_price.innerHTML/215)
$('input[id="te_li_yr_seats_form"]').val(te_li_yr_price.innerHTML/215)


/* PSEUDO CODE BELOW */

if $("#te_li_yr_seats_html").html = 2 then
my_new_variable = 70

elseif $("#te_li_yr_seats_html").html = 3 then
my_new_variable = 100

elseif $("#te_li_yr_seats_html").html = 4 then
my_new_variable = 130

elseif $("#te_li_yr_seats_html").html = 5 then
my_new_variable = 160

elseif $("#te_li_yr_seats_html").html = 6 then
my_new_variable = 190

elseif $("#te_li_yr_seats_html").html = 7 then
my_new_variable = 220

elseif $("#te_li_yr_seats_html").html = 8 then
my_new_variable = 250

/* then apply to HTML */
$("#my_new_variable_html").html(my_new_variable)
```

Comment: To *get* the HTML value, use `$("..").html()`.  And to compare values use `===` (or just `==` if comparing `"2"` with `2` - `.html()` will return a string.    In this case, just create a variable:  `var seats = te_li_yr_price.innerHTML/215` then `$("#te_li_yr_seats_html").html(seats)` and `if (seats === 2)` etc (or use a `switch`)

Comment: `my_new_var = seats * 30 + 10`?

Comment: Thank you for both of these comments I think I have it working now.

Answer (score 0):

The whole thing is hard to grasp, but here is a version that is easier to change. Note I have converted all the script to jQuery instead of mixing it with plain JS DOM access

I am using a ternary for the lookup to make sure that you do not get an error if the perSeat is larger than the lookup table

```js
const $te_li_yr_price = $("#te_li_yr_price_base");
const $te_li_yr_slider = $("#te_li_yr_slider");
const $te_li_yr_price_html = $("#te_li_yr_price_html");
const $te_li_yr_price_form = $("#te_li_yr_price_form");
const $te_li_yr_seats_html = $("#te_li_yr_seats_html");
const $te_li_yr_seats_form = $("#te_li_yr_seats_form");
const $my_new_variable_html = $("#my_new_variable_html");

const lookup = [0, 0, 70, 100, 130, 160, 190, 220, 250];

$te_li_yr_slider.on("input", function() {
  let val = this.value; // string
  let formattedVal = val.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","); // now with thousand separators
  let perSeat = parseInt(val / 215);
  $te_li_yr_price.html(val);
  $te_li_yr_price_html.html(formattedVal);
  $te_li_yr_price_form.val(te_li_yr_priceval);
  $te_li_yr_seats_html.html(perSeat);
  $te_li_yr_seats_form.val(perSeat);
  // if perSeat is <2 or outside the lookup table, give default value
  $my_new_variable_html.html(
    perSeat < 2 || perSeat >= lookup.length ? val : lookup[perSeat]
  );
}).trigger("input"); // initialise
```

Comment: Thank you appreciate this. I think I have found a solution based on the first comment received which is more to my basic level ;)

Comment: I strongly recommend you look and try to understand what I coded since it will help you in the long run